# Consistently Missing First UDP Packet in Buffered Mode with Python and ATI Sensor

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp

I'm working with an [ATI Gamma IP65](https://www.ati-ia.com/products/ft/ft_models.aspx?id=Gamma+IP65) sensor and trying to capture UDP packets in Python. The sensor has two modes: real-time (one sample per packet) and buffered (multiple samples per packet). Here's the issue: when I switch to buffered mode, Python consistently skips the first packet. This doesn't happen in real-time mode. Wireshark shows the first packet arriving in both modes, so it's getting to the machine.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- The socket is definitely bound before the sensor starts sending.
- I've played around with the buffer size in recvfrom, even going way over what I thought was necessary.
- Firewall and security software have been ruled out.
- I've tried tweaking socket options like `SO_REUSEADDR` and `SO_RCVBUF`.

I'm running this on Ubuntu `22.04.1` with Python `3.10`. Here's a snippet of the code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.bind(('', 10000))  # Example port

print("Ready to receive sensor data...")
while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print(f"Got data from {addr}")
```

The real puzzle is why this only happens with the first packet in buffered mode. Given UDP's unreliability, I'd expect some randomness, but this is consistently the first packet that's missed. Also, the packet is not missed by Wireshark, so it definitely arrived on my machine. Hence, I believe that the *missing packet* possibility is completely ruled out.

Has anyone faced something similar, or do you have any suggestions on what else I could check or try? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!